# Lowest bound on logarthmic equation with floor

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I have the following equation (log base 10):

$$\frac{x}{10^{\lfloor \log x/10 \rfloor}}$$
how can I show what the maximum value of this expression can be?
i.e. $\frac{x}{10^{\lfloor \log x/10 \rfloor}} < y$.

Comment: Is your equation meant to be $$\frac{x}{10 \lfloor \log x \rfloor}$$

Comment: ah no by ** i meant to say to the power, how do you guys write these equations?

Comment: Edited it in for you.

Comment: @barakmanos could you please show your steps on how you managed to get there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## For your original question:

Let $n$ denote the number of decimal digits in the integer part of $x$:

- $x = d_{1} \dots d_{n}$
- $\lfloor\log{x}\rfloor = n-1$
- $10^{\lfloor\log{x}\rfloor} = 1\underbrace{0\dots0}_{n-1\text{ times}}$

---

Therefore:

$$\frac{x}{10^{\lfloor\log{x}\rfloor}} = \frac{d_{1} \dots d_{n}}{1\underbrace{0\dots0}_{n-1\text{ times}}}<10^1$$

---

## For your updated question:

Let $n$ denote the number of decimal digits in the integer part of $x$:

- $x = d_{1} \dots d_{n}$
- $\lfloor\log{x}\rfloor = n-1$
- $\lfloor\log{x/10}\rfloor = n-2$
- $10^{\lfloor\log{x/10}\rfloor} = 1\underbrace{0\dots0}_{n-2\text{ times}}$

---

Therefore:

$$\frac{x}{10^{\lfloor\log{x/10}\rfloor}} = \frac{d_{1} \dots d_{n}}{1\underbrace{0\dots0}_{n-2\text{ times}}}<10^2$$